# How do I setup an EKS cluster with managed node groups to have private docker hub access on all namespaces?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks, dockerhub

I use the terraform module `terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws` to deploy an EKS cluster using managed node groups with no launch template.

```
module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "17.20.0"

  cluster_name    = "something"
  cluster_version = "1.21"

  vpc_id  = "some-vpc-id"
  subnets = ["eks-specific-subnets"]

  manage_worker_iam_resources = true

  node_groups = {
    main = {
      name_prefix = "something-"

      additional_tags = {
        "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/something" = "owned"
        "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled"   = true
      }

      ami_type       = "AL2_x86_64"
      disk_size      = 50
      instance_types = ["m5.large"]

      min_capacity  = 1
      max_capacity  = 100
      capacity_type = "SPOT"

      update_config = {
        max_unavailable_percentage = 50
      }

      subnets = ["private-subnets"]
    }
  }

  write_kubeconfig = false
}
```

How can I setup all namespaces/nodes in my cluster to have access to pull from my private docker account? Preferably, there is a way that I can manage the cluster through terraform with aws, kubernetes and helm providers. Do I need to use a replicator? Is there a way to configure it on the nodes so that it will work without `ServiceAccount` modifications?